# Android Studio: BottomNavigationBar; Error in Creating Layout Preview

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am attempting to follow android's [guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) on creating a bottomnavbar but I am having trouble getting it to render on the preview panel. The preview panel says that

```
"The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView"
```

and when I run the app and load up the page containing the bottomNavigationView the app crashes. It gives me the error...

```
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

I have tried looking up these errors and trying the solutions but nothing seems to be fixing the issue. The associated java file is extending from Activity. It might be that the dependencies which are listed below but I don't think this is the issue either

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
```

You try to add this

Answer (score 0):

into style.xml

delete `<item name="android:textColorSecondary"></item>` modify